# Does every state in the US require aircraft and pilot registration?

Tags: faa-regulations, usa, regulations

I'm aware of both [Washington](http://www.wsdot.wa.gov/aviation/Registration/Program.htm) and [Oregon](http://www.oregon.gov/aviation/pages/aircraftreg.aspx) requiring, by law, registration of aircraft and pilots who are based in the state.

Is this something *every* state does? Do states enforce it?

Comment: In 47 years of having a pilot's license in Oregon, I have never been asked to produce my Oregon pilot's registration. I don't carry it with me, although I think you're supposed to. I do still pay the fee every registration period for the simple reason that I think supporting the state aviation department is worthwhile.

Comment: Yeah, I just moved from WA to OR and brought an airplane with me, so I'm going through the steps. Registering got me thinking that it's gotta be more common than those two states, and here we are.

Comment: MT is another state that requires it, but not all states do: KY has no state registration for pilots or aircraft. You might get a better answer on law.SE for the part about state vs. federal jurisdiction but the big picture seems to be that states can require anything they want provided it doesn't conflict with the federal regs, e.g. OR can't require you to have your license in order to actually operate an aircraft, because that would conflict with the FARs. But that's my non-lawyer understanding, so don't rely on it :-)

Comment: No registration for pilots or aircraft in Kansas either

Comment: I'm not sure on aircraft (I'm buying a part-ownership, but don't know registration details), but I do know that in the state of Wisconsin I was not required to register as a pilot. Also, in Washington [pilots and mechanics don't have to register as of 2005](http://www.wsdot.wa.gov/aviation/Registration/PilotMechRegisNotReq.htm).

Comment: @Terry - *"837.030 Exhibition of certificate on demand. Every pilot operating within this state shall present a federal certificate of competency and state certificate of registration on demand. The certificate of registration shall be kept in the personal possession of the licensee when operating aircraft within this state and must be presented for inspection upon demand of **any passenger**, peace officer, official manager in charge of any airport, other aircraft operator or federal or state agent."* Technically as a passenger in your 747 I could have asked to see your registration :)

Comment: @RonBeyer Hmm, interesting. However, though I lived in Oregon the entire time that I was flying 747s, my flights did not originate from or arrive in Oregon, so I guess I was safe. LOL Also, I'm wondering what the penalty for non-compliance would be if a captain refused to present his state registration to a passenger. If there is no penalty, there is in effect now law.

Comment: @Terry I suppose a flight technically operates within the state even if it's just in the airspace. I'm not sure what recourse I would have as a passenger other than to report you to Oregon authorities. I suppose that a peace Officer could arrest you or an airport manager may be able to keep the flight from leaving until authorities arrived.

Comment: @Terry at least for aircraft, if it hasn't been registered, it is eligible for taxation (as I read the laws), which gives them a way to penalize you, I suppose - evasion of taxes.

Comment: Do airlines really ensure all their pilots have state registration in Oregon?

Comment: No.  Nevada does not enforce any sort of registration.  At least as a practical matter: there may or may not be some law or registration, but in ~20 years as an aircraft owner (and longer as a pilot) I never heard anything from the state other than a personal property tax.

Comment: @ZachLipton No. States cannot regulate interstate commerce, per the U.S. Constitution itself. Unless both endpoints are in Oregon, the state wouldn't be allowed to make such a requirement, just as they can't require truckers to get a license for every state they drive through. Incidentally, this is also why many online retailers don't charge state sales taxes - unless the company has a physical presence in the state of the customer, the transaction constitutes interstate commerce and is not taxable by the individual states. See Quill Corp v. North Dakota.

Comment: Washington State does not, in fact, have registration for pilots (or mechanics). This has been the case since 2005. See the page you linked to in your question, or [this page](http://www.wsdot.wa.gov/aviation/Registration/PilotMechRegisNotReq.htm) specifically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No.**

It varies from state to state. [New York](https://www.dot.ny.gov/divisions/operating/opdm/aviation/faqs), for example, requires tax payment but no aircraft or pilot registration. [New Jersey](http://www.state.nj.us/transportation/airwater/aviation/faqs.shtm) doesn't require any registration and didn't mention any taxes. In [Delaware](http://www.delreg.com/air.cfm), registration is required but taxes can be waived if you register your aircraft under your corporate, instead of your own name. [Iowa](http://www.iowadot.gov/aviation/aircraftregistration/registration.aspx) requires registration and so does [Ohio](https://www.dot.state.oh.us/Divisions/Operations/Aviation/Pages/AircraftRegistration.aspx).

I could not find a single resource which lists all states and their aircraft and pilot registration requirements. FAA does not have this information, probably because FAA does not care about state regulations.

We can create a Wiki on this topic here.